# QGIS Custom variable or Function to extract image "compass direction" from image url/path

Tags: qgis, image, qgis-custom-function, exif

I would like to create custom variable or a custom function to extract only "EXIF Camera Direction" of image from URL/path (field) of JPG images into QGIS. So i can directly write the formula within the expression or default value to get the exif camera direction.

I dont want to use ImportPhotos plugin because i already had the points feature and the field of image path, i also have empty field for the value of the camera direction, so how can i start for this learn?

the final custom function use like this:

img_exifdirection('field name of the img path')  ----->     value of the exif direction

note: im beginner in QGIS, but want to learn basic coding if needed to solve this

Answer (score 0):

This works assuming that the camera actually writes the image direction to the EXIF.  It seems that most cameras only write the location and maybe the altitude.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ExifTags
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS

def gps_azimuth(the_image):
    exifData = {}
    img = Image.open(the_image)
    exifDataRaw = img._getexif()
    
    for tag, value in list(exifDataRaw.items()):
        decodedTag = ExifTags.TAGS.get(tag, tag)
        exifData[decodedTag] = value
        image_direction = exifData['GPSInfo'][16]
    return image_direction
```